# static stacked list with no arrows

Tags: jquery-mobile

What would be the best way to do the list as in the image. When I tried doing as in the code text gets squashed into the image.

```
<div data-role="page" id="wrapper">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="stacked-list">
            <img src="images/icon_s1.jpg" alt="Online Subscription" class="ui-li-thumb"/>
            <div class="para">
                <h3 class="ui-li-heading">Online Subscription</h3>
                <p class="ui-li-desc">Online access to complete company profiles plus tools & analysis</p>

                </p> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /page -->
```

[Image of End Result http://move.clanteam.com/images/stacked-list_08.jpg](http://move.clanteam.com/images/stacked-list_08.jpg)

Comment: The image is unavailable on that host, try uploading the imgur.com and posting the link.

Comment: here is the link http://i.imgur.com/WErEK.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try list items with thumbnails?

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/lists-readonly.html

Comment: I tried them..But comes with a little arrow in the right side which I don't want.